# Python Regular expression to remove non unicode characters

Tags: python

I am trying to use python regular expression to remove some characters looks like non unicode from a string.
here is my code:

```
xxx='Juliana Gon\xe7alves Miguel'
t=re.sub('\w*','',xxx)
t
```

The result is like:

```
>>> xxx='Juliana Gon\xe7alves Miguel'
>>> t=re.sub('\w*','',xxx)
>>> t
' \xe7 '
```

This \xe7 is what I am trying to remove.
Can anyone have any ideas?

Comment: u don't to remove it. u want to convert it to the letter it should be, right?

Comment: I think I figured it out.`xxx='Juliana Gon\xe7alves Miguel'
t=re.sub(re.sub('\w*','',xxx).strip(),'',xxx)
t`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the desired output is

> 'Juliana Gonalves Miguel'

then the following regex should do the trick.

```
re.sub('(?![ -~]).', '', xxx)
```

`[ -~]`: short and readable version for all ASCII characters

`(?!)`: negative lookahead